# How to get specific subset of bash string

Tags: bash, awk, sh

For a string such as `"c-zyte5:p-6db39"` how can I parse it to get a specific subset, such as `p-6db39` - chopping off both the first 9 characters and the last?

Comment: `echo "c-zyte5:p-6db39" | sed -E 's/(.+):(.+)/\2/'`

Comment: `echo "c-zyte5:p-6db39" | grep -Eo '[^:]+$'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
foo='"c-zyte5:p-6db39"'
echo "${foo:9:-1}"            # prints p-6db39
```

(See [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

Answer (score 6):

Rather than substring indexing, you can also use the *parameter expansion* with substring removal to remove all characters from the left up though the first `':'`, e.g.

```
v="c-zyte5:p-6db39"
echo "${v##*:}"
```

**Result**

```
p-6db39
```

Comment: Note that in the question, the double-quotes are actually part of the string. So this answer produces `p-6db39"`.

Comment: Oh, then in that case `v="\"c-zyte5:p-6db39\""; v="${v%\"}"; echo "${v##*:}"` (trim the closing quote from the right, then trim from left until `':'`)